# JSON object's and arrays

Tags: javascript

I want to create a JSON object that is organized alphabetically as follows:

```js
var Dictionary = {};
var AlphabetString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for (x in AlphabetString) {
  Dictionary[x] = new Array();
}
var TestingString = ["apples, bannans, carrots, dice"];
for (x in TestingString) {
  Dictionary[TestingString.charAt(0)].push(TestingString);
}
```

So that Dictionary at each alphabet will give me an array of strings that have the same first letter as the identifier i.e. in my example Dictionary["a"] = ["apples"]. Is this the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Use `for (var x of …)` instead of `in`  and it'll work.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON object".

Comment: Do **NOT** use `for...in` on strings and arrays. Either use a `for...of` or a proper for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea), `for in` is a bad idea here. But in case if you still want to cling to it, there`s how you can do it.

```js
var Dictionary = {},
  elem, index;
var AlphabetString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var TestingString = ["apples", "bannans", "carrots", "dice"];
for (x in TestingString) {
  elem = TestingString[x];
  index = elem.charAt(0);
if (!Dictionary[index]) {
  Dictionary[AlphabetString[x]] = [];
}
Dictionary[index].push(elem);
}

console.dir(Dictionary);
```

Answer (score 1):

[You shouldn't use `for...in` loops to iterate array-like objects like arrays or strings.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1529630)

And `TestingString` should be an array of words.

I would use something like this (possibly checking if `firstChar` is the empty string):

```js
var dictionary = Object.create(null);
var testingArray = ["apples", "bannans", "carrots", "dice", "abc"];
for (var i=0; i<testingArray.length; ++i) {
  var firstChar = testingArray[i].charAt(0);
  if(!(firstChar in dictionary)) dictionary[firstChar] = [];
  dictionary[firstChar].push(testingArray[i]);
}
console.log(dictionary);
```

In ES6 you can iterate with `for...of`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with array methods

```
var AlphabetString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var Dictionary  = AlphabetString.split('').reduce( (res, curr) =>{
  res[curr] = []
  return res
}, {})

var TestingString = "apples, bannans, carrots, dice";
res = TestingString.split(/, /).forEach( item => Dictionary[item[0].toLowerCase()].push(item))
```